# What am I doing wrong (Simple Announcer Bot on Discord)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Disclaimer; I've never really looked a cold beyond once or twice prior to today.
The base Bot I got is from [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1tftZgPXbMbRDh2NXZLTmVvLVk&usp=sharing);
but I end up with this in cmd prompt when I try to run it:

```
C:\Users\aer\Desktop\discordbotjson>node start
C:\Users\aer\Desktop\discordbotjson\start.js:9
    var channel = client.channels.get("name", "general").id;
                  ^

ReferenceError: client is not defined
at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aer\Desktop\discordbotjson\start.js:9:16)
at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
at Client.emit (events.js:166:7)
at WebSocket.websocket.onmessage (C:\Users\aer\Desktop\discordbotjson\node_modules\discord.js\lib\Client\InternalClient.js:1047:13)
at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\aer\Desktop\discordbotjson\node_modules\ws\lib\WebSocket.js:414:14)
at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
at WebSocket.emit (events.js:172:7)
at Receiver.ontext (C:\Users\aer\Desktop\discordbotjson\node_modules\ws\lib\WebSocket.js:797:10)
at C:\Users\aer\Desktop\discordbotjson\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:473:18
at Receiver.applyExtensions (C:\Users\aer\Desktop\discordbotjson\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:360:5)
```

---

This is what the `start.json` looks like:

```
var Discord = require("discord.js");
var schedule = require('node-schedule');
var AuthDetails = require("./auth.json");

var bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on('ready', () => {
// change channel name to name of channel or just set to equal the     channel ID if you already know it.
var channel = client.channels.get("name", "general").id; 

var rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule(); // Creates new Recurrence Rule
rule.minute = 0; // Must set to 0 or scheduled job will run every minute.
rule.hour = [14, 19, 20]; // Hours are based on your system's time.

var j = schedule.scheduleJob(rule, function() {
    bot.channels.get("id", channel).sendMessage("Testing");
})

/* For different announcements:
rule.hour = 8; // Set different time. Use array like above for multiple hours.

var i = schedule.scheduleJob(rule, function() {
    bot.channels.get("id", channel).sendMessage("Announcement at 8AM");
})

// Repeat for more announcements
*/

console.log("Bot is ready.");
});

//login
bot.login(AuthDetails.email, AuthDetails.password);
```

Help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Try changing client.channels.get to bot.channels.get

Comment: You have no element named "client".  Did you mean "bot", perhaps?

Comment: This `var Discord = require("discord.js");` most probably should be: `var Discord = require("discord");`

Answer (score 3):

Some code examples you might find use `var client = new Discord.Client();`, some others use `var bot = new Discord.Client();`. They mean the same but use a different name, and since you're using the latter, you must replace all instances of the variable name `client` with `bot`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var Discord = require("discord.js");
var schedule = require('node-schedule');
var AuthDetails = require("./auth.json");
var bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on('ready', () => {
    var channel = bot.channels.get("name", "general").id;

    var rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
    rule.minute = 0;
    rule.hour = [14, 19, 20];

    var j = schedule.scheduleJob(rule, function() {
        bot.channels.get("id", channel).sendMessage("Testing");
    })

    console.log("Bot is ready.");
});

bot.login(AuthDetails.email, AuthDetails.password);
```

Answer (score 0):

Bot is your instance of a Discord Client it's normal that  `client.channels.()` doesn't return anything since client is not defined anywhere.

Just replace client with your instance of a client which is here "bot"

```
var channel = bot.channels.get("name", "general").id;
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work;
`var channel = bot.channels.find("name", "general");
channel.sendMessage("Hello Owner Just Restarted Me!");`

Answer (score -1):

Replace `var Discord = require("discord.js");` with `var bot = require("discord.js");`

Hope this helps!